# What frameworks are available in ASP.NET Core (ASP.NET 5) applications?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have seen various frameworks targeted in *project.json* files, using names such as `netcore50`, `dotnet`, `dnx451`, `net45`, and others. The [documentation for the "framework" section project.json](https://github.com/aspnet/home/wiki/Project.json-file#frameworks) does not (yet) specify how to use this section for different frameworks.

What frameworks are available and what name should be used in *project.json* to target each?

Comment: To the person that voted to close as asking for a software recommendation, this doesn't appear to be what's being asked if you read the question. The questions is about the Target Framework Monikers in ASP.NET 5 (if I got that term right).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**UPDATE 3**

Full list see [Target Frameworks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/target-frameworks#supported-frameworks).

The most common TFMs ASP.NET app developers need to know are:

- **`netcoreappx.y`** = An application that targets **.NET Core x.y** (e.g. `netcoreapp1.0` = .NET Core 1.0)
- **`netstandardx.y`** = A library that targets **.NET Standard x.y**. (e.g. `netstandard2.0` = .NET Standard 2.0). .NET Standard libraries can work on desktop .NET, Windows Phone, Mono, and others.
- **`net4xy`** = A library or console app that targets desktop **.NET Framework 4.x.y** (e.g. `net452` or `net46`)

**UPDATE 2** (Dec 9, 2015)

<strike>Somewhat official docs are now available from dotnet. See [.NET Platform Standard → Nuget](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#nuget)</strike>

<strike>For libraries targeting multiple platforms that adhere to the [.NET Standard](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md), these TFMs (target framework monikers) are available.~</strike>

**UPDATE** (Aug 12, 2015)

[This Nuget blog post](http://blog.nuget.org/20150729/Introducing-nuget-uwp.html#new-target-frameworks) shows additional TFMs available for nuget. It also explains the `dotnet` TFM.

**Original response**

Although this is not official documentation, [this blog post by Oren Novotny](http://oren.codes/2015/06/09/pcls-net-core-dnx-and-uwp/) has an excellent table showing the different target framework monikers.

Comment: DNX is no longer a living term. This answer (and the images) should be updated.

Answer (score 1):

As of right now there are only <strike>two</strike> three with any package support.

.Net Framework 4.5.1 = dnx451
.Net Framework 4.5.2 = dnx452
.Net Core 5.0 = dnx50

.NET Framework 4.6.0 (dnx46) will be released in the near future.

Still it depends on what you mean by 'available'.  Anyone could release a new framework is they wanted to, that cat is now out of the bag.  However by default dnu uses the project.json to find dependencies by looking at the main feed on nuget.org.  Right now on nuget.org those are the only dnx framework dependencies.

For example take a look at the microsoft.aspnet.mvc nuget page:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/6.0.0-beta4

```
Dependencies

DNX 4.5.1
Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization (≥ 1.0.0-beta4)
Microsoft.AspNet.Cors (≥ 1.0.0-beta4)
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor (≥ 6.0.0-beta4)
Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Memory (≥ 1.0.0-beta4)

DNXCore 5.0
Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization (≥ 1.0.0-beta4)
Microsoft.AspNet.Cors (≥ 1.0.0-beta4)
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor (≥ 6.0.0-beta4)
Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Memory (≥ 1.0.0-beta4)
```

Edit: there also was a aspnet50 and aspnetcore50 in earlier beta versions but they have been deprecated and should be replaced with dnx451 and dnxcore50 respectively.

Comment: There are definitely more than two. MVC only uses 2.

Comment: You stated packages.json which would indicates dnx environment correct?  There are lots of FTMs but they are not valid targets for dnx.  In addition to the two listed there is also dnx452 and dnx460 will probably be the primary non-core target by the time VS reaches RTM.

Comment: just published a package on nugget and .Net Framework 4.5.1 != dnx451. `dnx451` is .Net Framework 4.5.1 over the dnx execution environment while `net451` is .Net Framework 4.5.1 classic.

Comment: The term DNX has officially been removed, so hope this answer can be updated accordingly.