# Write to EventLog in .Net Core

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, dnx

I need a way to write to Windows' event viewer in my app that's using dnx. But, the `EventLog` class isn't available in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace so I'm stuck. Is there any other way to write to the EventViewer?

Comment: Did you see https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog/

Comment: If your app has to target Core, then I don't think so - event log is not a cross-platform concept.  If your app can target net461 or other full .net platforms, then you can use the package mentioned by @StingyJack

Comment: @stephen.vakil how can I target net461 and core from my project.json?

Comment: via the `frameworks` section of `project.json`  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763115/what-frameworks-are-available-in-asp-net-core-asp-net-5-applications for some options

Comment: @stephen.vakil Is it possible to conditionally load namespaces and use classes depending on what framework is active? I want to run `EventLog` **only** when dnx461 is active, otherwise do something else.

Comment: AFAIK you can always conditionally load assemblies, but detecting when may be the hard part. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8543850/16391

Comment: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging is quite flexible - besides the Event Viewer compatible provider as mentioned by @StingyJack there is also Serilog (https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Getting-Started) which I think is worth considering for platform independent file logging.

Answer (score 22):

Add from `NuGet`  `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog` `Version 2.1.1`

```
CM> Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog -Version 2.1.1
```

Include the namespace `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog` in the `Program.cs` file

This resolved my problem.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you edit your answer to clarify how this answers the OP's question, please.

Comment: you can also install-Package System.Diagnostics.EventLog with version 6.0.0

Answer (score 13):

Writing to the Event Log in .Net Core requires first a Nuget package installation

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog -Version 3.1.2
```

Note that the correct version to install depends on the version of .Net Core you are running.The package above was tested OK with .Net Core.

Then we need to add EventLog. In the Program class we can do this like so:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog;

namespace SomeAcme.SomeApi
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                    logging.AddEventLog(new EventLogSettings()
                    {
                        **SourceName = "SomeApi",
                        LogName = "SomeApi",**
                        Filter = (x, y) => y >= LogLevel.Warning
                    });
                    logging.AddConsole();
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

And our appsettings.json file includes setup:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SomeApi;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  **"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },**
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

We can inject the ILogger instance

```
using SomeAcme.SomeApi.SomeModels;
using SomeAcme.SomeApi.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SomeAcme.SomeApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ISomeService _healthUnitService;
        private readonly ILogger<SomeController> _logger;

        public SomeController(ISomeService someService, ILogger<SomeController> logger)
        {
            _someService= someService;
            _logger = logger;
        }
        // GET: api/Some
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<SomeModel> GetAll()
        {
            return _someService.GetAll();
        }
    }
}
```

More advanced use, add a global exception handler inside Configure method of Startup class in .Net Core:

```
  //Set up a global error handler for handling Unhandled exceptions in the API by logging it and giving a HTTP 500 Error with diagnostic information in Development and Staging
        app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
        {
            errorApp.Run(async context =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 500; // or another Status accordingly to Exception Type
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

                var status = context.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();

                var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                if (error != null)
                {
                    var ex = error.Error;
                    string exTitle = "Http 500 Internal Server Error in SomeAcme.SomeApi occured. The unhandled error is: ";
                    string exceptionString = !env.IsProduction() ? (new ExceptionModel
                    {
                        Message = exTitle + ex.Message,
                        InnerException = ex?.InnerException?.Message,
                        StackTrace = ex?.StackTrace,
                        OccuredAt = DateTime.Now,
                        QueryStringOfException = status?.OriginalQueryString,
                        RouteOfException = status?.OriginalPath
                    }).ToString() : new ExceptionModel()
                    {
                        Message = exTitle + ex.Message,
                        OccuredAt = DateTime.Now
                    }.ToString();
                    try
                    {
                        _logger.LogError(exceptionString);
                    }
                    catch (Exception err)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(err);
                    }
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(exceptionString, Encoding.UTF8);
                }
            });
        });
```

And finally a helper model to pack our exception information into.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SomeAcme.SomeApi.Models
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Exception model for generic useful information to be returned to client caller
    /// </summary>
    public class ExceptionModel
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string InnerException { get; set; }
        public DateTime OccuredAt { get; set; }
        public string StackTrace { get; set; }
        public string RouteOfException { get; set; }
        public string QueryStringOfException { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The tricky bit here is to get hold of a logger inside the Startup class.
You can inject ILoggerFactory for this and just do :

```
  _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Startup>();
```

Where _logger is used in the global error handler above.

Now back again to the question of how to write to the event log, look at the source code for **SomeController** above. We inject ILogger here.
Just use that instance and it offers different methods for writing to your configured logs. Since we added in the Program class event log, this happens automatically.

Before you test out the code above, run the following Powershell script as administrator to get your event log source:

New-EventLog -LogName SomeApi -SourceName SomeApi

What I like with this approach is that if we do everything correct, the exceptions pops up inside the SomeApi source nicely and not inside the application event log (clutter IMHO).

Comment: The PowerShell syntax for creating the event log is `New-EventLog -LogName SomeApi -Source SomeApi`

Comment: Yes, and if the -LogName and -Source has same value the log will also be visible in Event Viewer as an individual node in the list of logs to the left of eventvwr instead of being mixed with other logs, usually Applications log.

Answer (score 1):

Good news! EventLog is already [ported to corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/24344) and will be available in [.NET Core 2.1](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/milestone/12).

Right now you can download a preview package System.Diagnostics.EventLog from their [MyGet](https://dotnet.myget.org/gallery/dotnet-core) feed.

Answer (score 1):

it is available in 2.0 but you have to install the compatibility pack.
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25440

**Here for more information:**
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/16/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

`EventLog.WriteEntry` is a static method in Diagnostics:

`System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(source, message, MessageType, EventId);`

I've been calling it for years & it works fine. 1 line of code vs all the other answers & it directly answers the question asked

Defaults to the application event log. Using custom logs takes more work, including reg key permissions.

Comment: The issue is that the source must exist before you use it. According to the documentation, you have to create the source and exit. It will be available the second time the application is run. This makes it a good candidate for running inside an installer project. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.source?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: So, read the registry 1st. Supposed to be doing that anyway anytime anything outside an app is going to be accessed. If you use a custom event log, registry permissions also need to be modified. 

However, if you use the App or System event log, then the source already exists, if I'm interpreting your post correct.y

Comment: The issue is usually administrative rights. If your application has regular user permissions and the user can't elevate without an admin, you're going to need an installer with admin permissions. If you want your installer to run in a per-user mode then you can't do this at all.

Comment: Use either the Application or System Event Log... built into all Windows flavors & it eliminates registry changes & permissions. And no, you don't need admin permissions.

Comment: We are already talking about the Application log. Did you try it? There is a "Source" column in event viewer. This is where you put the name of your application so you can filter the Application log for your application. You cannot add a new application to the list of registered application sources without admin. You must be using an existing source. That existing source was either created with admin permissions or is not unique to your application.

Comment: Don't confuse EventLog.WriteEntry with EventLog.WriteEvent. They are different. WriteEntry just adds the params into the event log. WriteEntry is totally different & outside this scope of the original question. My apps are hosted on XenApp & no users havre admin access...yeah, I do use WriteEntry. it works.

Comment: Irrelevant. I'm not sure how you keep missing the topic being **source**, what is the string you are feeding in to the `source`?
> "You must create and configure the event source before writing the first entry with the source. ... If the operating system has not refreshed its list of event sources, and you attempt to write an event with the new source, the write operation will fail. ... You must have administrative rights on the computer to create a new event source."
Read the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.writeentry

Comment: OK-- I re-tested. For the Application event log: Using "Application" as the event source attribute does work as I've previously described, it's built into Windows & does not require admin permissions or reg edits. Trying to use a custom source, yeah it requires admin permissions (add the key when it's being packaged to distribute being 1 option).

So, yes-- Use "application" as the source and it's built into Windows already & does work, no reg edits, no admin permissions needed.