# Cannot add Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog package with .NET Core 2 application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, coreclr, .net-core-logging

so as per the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#eventlog)  we can add EvventLog as one of the logging provider. However when i add `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog` package in my .NET Core 2 Web Api application i see yellow explaination mark like below

[image]

With such warning i was still able to add EventLog in BuildWebHost method

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseApplicationInsights()
                .UseUrls("http://*:40006")                
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext,logging)=> 
            {
                logging.AddEventLog(new Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogSettings()
                {                    
                    SourceName = "MySource",
                });
            })
            .Build();
```

however when i run the application i get error

> Could not load type 'System.Diagnostics.EventLog' from assembly
>   'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.'

and Warning

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog 2.0.0'
>   was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the
>   project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may
>   not be fully compatible with your project.

Comment: I have heard somebody from Microsoft mention that Event logging will be included in an extension pack delivered in .Net Core 2.1. There is also an earlier Stackoverflow question on the same subject https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131217/write-to-eventlog-in-net-core

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success with this in .NET Core 2.x:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Foo
{
    public enum EventLogType
    {
        EVENTLOG_SUCCESS = 0x000,
        EVENTLOG_AUDIT_FAILURE = 0x0010,
        EVENTLOG_AUDIT_SUCCESS = 0x0008,
        EVENTLOG_ERROR = 0x0001,
        EVENTLOG_INFORMATION = 0x0004,
        EVENTLOG_WARNING = 0x0002
    }

    public static class EventLog
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "RegisterEventSource", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern long RegisterEventSource(string lpUNCServerName, string lpSourceName);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DeregisterEventSource", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int DeregisterEventSource(IntPtr hHandle);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int ReportEvent(IntPtr hHandle, ushort wType, ushort wCategory, uint dwEventID, IntPtr uSid, ushort wStrings, uint dwDataSize, string[] lpStrings, byte bData);

        public static void Write(string source, string message, EventLogType type)
        {
            int lastError = -1;
            IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
            string[] strs = new string[2];

            long rawHandle64 = RegisterEventSource(null, source);
            handle = new IntPtr(rawHandle64);

            lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

            if (lastError == 0)
            {
                strs[0] = source;
                strs[1] = message;

                int res = ReportEvent(handle, (ushort)type, 0, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 2, 0, strs, 0);

                lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

                DeregisterEventSource(handle);

                lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i will wait..:) even i serilog.sinks.eventlog does not work with .NET Core 2

Answer (score 0):

If using 2.0 you'll need to add a reference to package `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` as described in [ASP.NET Core and Windows Event Log](https://medium.com/@ans_ashkan/asp-net-core-and-windows-event-log-75770a80a666).