# How can I log events to the Event Viewer in an ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to log to the Event Viewer in an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API, hosted on Windows Server 2016 Standard.

I've got this in my controller:

```
private readonly ILogger<MyController> _logger;
private readonly MyContext _context;

public TestController(MyContext context, ILogger<MyController> logger)
{
    _context = context;
    _logger = logger;
}
```

But I think I'm doing something wrong in my CreateWebHostBuilder() method in Program.cs because it's not working:

I had this:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

and I modified it to this:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
            });
```

But I must be doing something wrong... Any ideas? I read here that apparently EVent Viewer logging is now baked into .Net Core 2.1 [Write to EventLog in .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131217/write-to-eventlog-in-net-core)

Comment: Looking at another example, I've added loggerFactory.AddEventLog(); to my Configure() methos in Startup.cs, but it's not finding the AddEventLog() method ('ILoggerFactory' does not contain a definition for 'AddEventLog'...)

Answer (score 14):

For anyone who stumbles upon this using .NET Core 2.2, the Event Log logger (from *Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog*) should now be added in the `Program.cs`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddEventLog();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

This is noted at the bottom of the [.NET Core Logging docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#windows-eventlog-provider).

**UPDATE:** In case someone still lands here post .NET Core 2.2, this is still relevant for [.NET Core 3.1 logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#windows-eventlog-provider).

Comment: Note you need to add another nuget package:
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog
which not included in the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging package

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I had to add *Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog* to the project (from Nuget).

Then, in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
   loggerFactory.AddEventLog();
}
```

Comment: Weird thing is that it works on my development machine (Windows 10) but not on my server (Windows Server 2016 Standard) :(

Comment: It's most likely a permissions or group policy problem if it works on Windows 10 and not Server 2016